# PHP Soap MustUnderstand

Tags: php, zend-framework, soap

I have a soap server in Zend Framework and have added a filter before the request hits the soap_server to parse the header and allow wsse. This works fine.

Yesterday I received a call with the attribute MustUnderstand=1 on the Security element in the header. The soap_server then throws: header not understood.

Is it possible to do a workaround to have zend_soap_server ignore the mustunderstand=1 on the header?

Answer (score 5):

Just implement a function called as the Attribute and do nothing inside it if it's not necessary.

Dont use "return" statement inside it, because it could return the message without process the body

Example

```
<SOAP-ENV:Header>
    <wsa5:To SOAP-ENV:mustUnderstand="true">http://www.xxx.yyy.zzz/</wsa5:To>
    <wsa5:Action SOAP-ENV:mustUnderstand="true">someData</wsa5:Action>
</SOAP-ENV:Header>
```

You must implement a class like this:

```
Class MySoapServer{
    private $bar;
    private $foo;

    public function To( $data )
    {
        $this->bar = $data;
    } 

    public function Action( $data )
    {
         //do Nothing!
    } 

    public function Method1( $message )  
    {
         //....
         return $returnedValues;
    }

}
```